# CKEditor syntax error in "cke_reset" css class

Tags: ckeditor

Does someone knows this CKEditor (4.2) syntax error?

```
SyntaxError: syntax error                             /ckeditor.js Line 358
    .cke_reset{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;background:transparen
```

I already tried to use basic and advanced versions.

Comment: This looks like there is CSS where JavaScript is expected. Are you sure there is no mix-up with files or something? What is on line 358 in CKEditor.js?

Comment: @Pekka웃 ... sorry: http://pastie.org/8392454

Comment: Have you tried re-uploading the file (if it's on a web server)?

Comment: Could you post somewhere your entire `ckeditor.js`? The line you pasted does not contain CSS at all, so how could it be related to the error message?

Comment: @Reinmar, http://goo.gl/9DdWOh

Comment: This file is ok. It's exactly the `ckeditor.js` from 4.2.1 full package which works for millions of people ;). Make sure your backend or cache are not interfering.